# Android: creating a multidimensional array for a ListView Adapter

Tags: android

Here is what I have now:

```
private Object mainArray[] = {R.drawable.main_logo, "page_4"};
    private Object studioArray[] = {R.drawable.studio_logo, "page_5"};
    private Object gArray[] = {R.drawable.g_logo, "page_6"};
    private Object venues[] = {mainArray,studioArray,gArray};
```

I pass the venues array object to my adapter, however I can't get the size of the object: venues.size(); Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using an array, you should call

```
venues.length
```

instead of venues.size()

BUT:

> Like @arasmussen said in his final lines, you could use a more complex
>   data structure like an ArrayList too.

I don't know the context of you code, but normal arrays seem to be a bit akward in this situation. Since you create arrays of objects, you have no idea what is in your arrays (other than Objects). I guess the only reason you create arrays of Objects, is that you want to store ints and strings together.

A Map is more suitable for this kind of things, for it really defines what kind of objects you want to store, and also ensures that you cannot put other objects in it. Also, a Map will provide more functionality later on, when you need to search in your arrays and extract or values...

I would suggest something like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> main = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
main.put(R.drawable.main_logo, "page_4");

Map<Integer, String> studio = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
main.put(R.drawable.studio_logo, "page_5");

Map<Integer, String> gArray = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
main.put(R.drawable.g_logo, "page_6");

ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>> venues = new ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>>();
venues.add(main);
venues.add(studio);
venues.add(gArray);
```

Allthough, this might seem like an overkill. It really gives you much more flexibility later on. E.g. you can do things like this:

```
venues.size(); // Get the number of venues
```

and

```
for(Map<Integer, String> element : venues)
{
    if(element.containsKey(R.drawable.main_logo)){} // do something
    else if(element.containsValue("page 5")){} // do something else
}
```

Maybe i get a bit carried away though. But I don't like create arrays of Objects, since you have no idea of what exactly is in those arrays later on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like venues is an array of Objects, but it doesn't contain Objects, it contains arrays of Objects. So maybe rather than having an array of objects, you should make venues an array of arrays of objects.

Something like this perhaps?

```
private Object[] venues[] = {mainArray,studioArray,gArray};
```

I'm not really confident in this answer as I'm a C++ programmer but this is what I would try first. I believe you could use a more complex data structure like an ArrayList too that might provide you more functionality than just an array.